# Spring Boot: Create Custom Jsp Tag - Unable to find taglib

Tags: java, spring, jsp, taglib

I want to add a custom Jsp tag to Spring boot. But I can't figure out project structure/URI for the taglib definition

I tried searching for solutions, but they are too ... deprecated. Using web.xml stuff, or really old folder structure which spring boot doesn't support by default.

While trying to load jsp page o get this error
`org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to find taglib [ex] for URI: [/customTags.tld]`

This is my current folder structure

```
├───src
│   └───main
│       ├───java
│       │   └───com
│       │       └───training
│       │           └───bookstore
│       │               │   AppFrontend.java
│       │               │   Test.java
│       │               │
│       │               ├───controller
│       │               │       FrontendController.java
│       │               │       FrontendEndConfiguration.java
│       │               │
│       │               └───tag
│       │                       HelloTag.java
│       │
│       ├───resources
│       │   │   application.properties
│       │   │   custom.tld
│       │   │
│       │   └───META-INF
│       │       └───resources
│       │               custom.tld
│       │               index.jsp
│       │
│       └───webapp
```

application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

pom.xml - I am inheriting from parent module, so version are missing

```
    <artifactId>bookstore-frontend</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> <!-- JSTL -->
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1-b03</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.training</groupId>
            <artifactId>bookstore-shared</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.training</groupId>
            <artifactId>boostore-storage-client</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

HelloTag

```
public class HelloTag extends SimpleTagSupport {
    private String message;

    public void setMessage(String msg) {
        this.message = msg;
    }
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    public void doTag()
            throws JspException, IOException {
        if (message != null) {
            JspWriter out = getJspContext().getOut();
            out.println( message );
        } else {
            getJspBody().invoke(sw);
            getJspContext().getOut().println(sw.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

custom.tld

```
<taglib>
<tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
<jsp-version>2.0</jsp-version>
<short-name>Example TLD with Body</short-name>

<tag>
    <name>Hello</name>
    <tag-class>com.training.bookstore.tag</tag-class>
    <body-content>scriptless</body-content>
    <attribute>
        <name>message</name>
    </attribute>
</tag>
</taglib>
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<%@ taglib prefix = "ex" uri = "/customTags.tld"%>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <strong>Hello from index page</strong>
        <ex:Hello message = "This is custom tag" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated,
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So project structure was good. The reason why it couldnt find taglib is that uri is not a filepath its a domain (you can make it up)

in tld file add this `<uri>http://whatever.jstldomainexample</uri>`

custom.tld

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd"
        version="2.1">
    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <short-name>jstlContains</short-name> (could be anything)
    <uri>http://whatever.jstldomainexample</uri> (could vary as per choice)

<tag>
    <name>Hello</name>
    <tag-class>com.training.bookstore.tag.HelloTag</tag-class>
    <body-content>scriptless</body-content>

    <attribute>
        <name>message</name>
    </attribute>

</tag>
</taglib>
```

and in jsp call the custom tag using
`<%@ taglib prefix="ex" uri="http:/whatever.jstldomainexample"%>`
index.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="ex" uri="http://bojan.jstldomain"%>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <strong>Hello from index page</strong>
        <ex:Hello message = "This is custom tag" />
    </body>
</html>
```